# Printing tens of pages in Silverlight freezes the computer

Tags: silverlight-4.0, printing

we have a Silverlight 4 app that prints a multi-page report. When the number of pages exceeds 20 or 30 (depending on the computer), the printing completely blocks the computer and users are unable to use it.
That is due to the huge print job size - each page takes about 170MB, so a 10 page document results in nearly 2gig!
In a comment from the page http://wildermuth.com/2009/11/27/Silverlight_4_s_Printing_Support (see comment by Marshall Agnew from December 3, 2009) I found that "Silverlight Printing does currently allow users to specify Color/Grayscale, Orientation and Resolution(DPI)..."
However, I am unable to find any info as to how this is done.
We are printing a black and white document, text only, so grayscale (or even black&white, if that were possible) would be fine with us.
Thanks for any help on how to decrease the size of the print job or find an alternative solution to printing multi-page reports in SL4.
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that silverlight print raw image bytes by rendering images from XAML. Not optimized at all.

Try generate XPS or PDF files from your client and allow the user to save it before print.

XPS are relatively easy to generate because they use XAML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771669.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This whole thing irritates the heck out of me.  If I have to print to PDF to print, then Silverlight is just NOT ready for prime time.  I built a large scale application in Silverlight.  Printing works for the most part, but in some printers the large print jobs cause errors and lock up the application or the computer.  This is ridiculous to me!  Silverlight cannot be used for business apps with slap stick print support.  In fact an even worse bug is that there is no page filtering either.  If you select pages 2 and 5 of a 8 page document it will simply print page 1 and 2.

I'm so embarrassed that my application has now inherited the problems of Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking too much of the Silverlight printing engine.  You would probably get better performance if you print from a PDF rather than directly from Silverlight.

Have you looked into some third-party Silverlight reporting tools?  Many of them will convert a report to PDF, Excel, and other formats.

Comment: Are you saying, that printing 20 pages is too much to ask of Silverlight version 4? About the tools - are any of them free? Thanks.